# check if a folder contains images of any types in php

Tags: php, image

I would like to know if its possible to check in a given folder whether it contains images of any types.

For example : Say my folder location is `/var/www/html/project/images/`

I want to check in images folder, if it contains any images in it...

It can have following types `.jpeg, .jpg, .png, .gif`

There is no name for images.

Comment: I don't think there is a function for this however you could scan a directory and check if any of the contents are images. If you have an image stop and return true or you could count them or store them. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) can be used for this problem. Glob is a function that can find pathnames that matches a pattern, similar to [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Here's some sample code that will search for jpg, png, and gif files in the folder and then echo out the names of these files.

```
<?php
$path = '/var/www/html/project/images/';
$files = glob($path."*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($files);
?>
```

If you simply want to check whether there are images or not, use the following code instead of `print_r($files);`:

```
if (!empty($files)) {
    echo 'There are images in this folder';
}
else {
    echo "No images were found here"; 
}
?>
```

If you want to know more about recursively checking directories, check out [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

Answer (score 1):

This should work, didn't test it.

```
$images = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');
$files = scandir('your/dir');
$found = false;
foreach($files as $key => $value) {
    $ext = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(in_array($ext,$images)) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

echo $found;
```

Comment: A bit excessive code for what the poster is trying to do, check out my code. It's much simpler.

Comment: @Domecraft: I read your answer before the edit, and couldn't understand how it would scan only the one directory. After the edit it does seem like the better option. I'll leave this answer anyway, incase someone needs a more specific solution (or doesn't like yours :P ) Upvoted yours as it's technically the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal via [preg_help](http://php.net/preg_grep) which will filter filenames by passing a regex to it.

Check this code:

```
<?php    
$dir_f = "/var/www/html/project/images/";
$files = preg_grep('~\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$~', scandir($dir_f));
if (!empty($files)) {
    echo 'yaaay, I got images in my dir !';
}
else {
    echo "Oh god, no images here !"; 
}
?>
```